# Issue with $.each in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok so I have an issue when I try to use $.each to iterate through this JSON. I'm trying to access just the posts information.

[image: JSON]

This is my code so far.

```
var newPosts = <? echo(getPosts($optionsArray)); ?>;
            var postJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newPosts));
            console.log(postJSON);
            alert(postJSON);

            //Make sure the div is emptied before we append to it
            $("#Posts").empty();

            //Append new data
            $.each(postJSON.posts, function(key, value){
                alert(value);
            })
```

The console log displays the information I want but I get no information from the alert. Nothing pops up. Been crackin at this for a bit.

Comment: getPosts() must be dumping out json text already, so unless it's double-encoding your data, the whole json.parse business is pointless. why not just `$.each(newPosts, ...)`?

Comment: Line #2: parse(stringify()) -- why?

Comment: What if you try alert( value.blog_name ); for example?

Comment: Marc B. Yeah I don't even know. That helped. Thank you for your answer. Problem solved :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse = turns a formatted JSON string and creates an object...
JSON.stringify = turns a JavaScript object into a JSON string....

So you are turning it into a string and then back into an object. Get rid of JSON.parse if you want to print out the string properly. 
It should look like this:

```
    var jString = JSON.stringify(newPosts);
    alert(jString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `console.dir(postJSON)` to make sure that the JSON has an array called `posts`.

If not there's your answer.

Comment: It does exist. In fact if I do console.dir(postJSON.posts); it gives me the information i want to iterate through. I just can't actually iterate...through it XD.